# Can not connect CI to google-cloud-sql?

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-cloud-sql

I just follow some blog and as well as follow many answers but still I am getting below error.

```
Severity: Warning

Message: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

Line Number: 228

Backtrace:

File: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\beta\ECI\application\controllers\Login.php
Line: 6
Function: __construct

File: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\beta\ECI\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

A Database Error Occurred

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: C:/inetpub/wwwroot/beta/ECI/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 436
```

I have instance ID of 2nd generation

```
$db['default']['socket'] = '/cloudsql/abc:us-central1:xxxx';
```

I already create one instance and now I want to connect this instance into my APP. I setup my IP address into this created instance but still I am unable to pulling data from cloud DB. Any one have idea about that

Answer (score 0):

The error `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)` indicates that there is a password set for the root user. If you have set a password, you will need to put the same password in your application config.

Comment: thanks for reply but I have set password still it indicate same error.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to change the default password of the root user and try to connect with your new root password. This solved the problem for me.